# Merge array who is inside an object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to merge two object, with an array inside, together :

`res : [ { data: [1,2,3] }, { data: [4,5,6] } ]`

And the result will look like this :

`res : [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

How can I get there ?

Thank you !

Comment: Answer below (at least my attempt at it). Please take a look at SO's [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for your future questions though. Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.map` as follows:

```
const input = [{ data: [1, 2, 3] }, { data: [4, 5, 6] }];
const output = [].concat(...input.map((item) => item.data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) along with [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
let input = [ { data: [1,2,3] }, { data: [4,5,6] } ];

let result = input.reduce((result, entry) => result.concat(entry.data), []);

console.log(result);
```